# Systemwide setting of textcolor in UIMenuitem

Tags: ios, uimenuitem

I want to change the color in the UIMenuItem. I have changed the color of [UIButton appearance] and this affects the UIMenuItems (copy/paste/etc).

Is there a way to set another text color than the button text color?

Comment: What do you mean by System wide?

Comment: I mean all over the app

Comment: I would think you would use `UIAppearance` to change when `UILabel` [when contained in (docs link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:) `UIMenuItem`. I have been able to change the background color to the menu item button, but it does not display well with the original shape of the menu item. How did you do it?